# Volcar salida de programa en archivo

Tags: python

Buenas tardes,

Estoy realizando un programita que sea capaz de obtener cierta información de dos dominios introducidos por el usuario. Me gustaria volcar la información obtenida en un archivo de texto para luego analizarla pero estoy teniendo algunos problemas con eso..

La pregunta concreta seria ¿donde deberia definir la creación del archivo?

```
 # -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

import dns.resolver
import dns.query 
import os
import sys


print" "                                       
print"___________________ INFO-SCANNER DOMAIN ___________________ "
print"                                                            "
print"                Introduzca dos dominios                     "
print"         se le mostrará la siguiente información            "
print"                                                            "
print"          IP, MailServers(MX), DNS(NS) y WHOIS              "
print"                                                            "
print"                    Ejemplo: site.com                       "
print"                                                            "
print"                 Para interrumpir Ctrl + C                  "
print" "


#Defino una funcion para la consulta DNS
def get_dns(domain):


    try:


                ansA,ansMX,ansNS=(dns.resolver.query(domain,'A', raise_on_no_answer=False),
                                  dns.resolver.query(domain,'MX', raise_on_no_answer=False),
                                  dns.resolver.query(domain, 'NS', raise_on_no_answer=False))





                print()
                print"_______________________ RESPUESTA IP _______________________ "
                print()
                print ansA.response.to_text() 
                print()
                print"_______________________ RESPUESTA MX _______________________ "
                print()
                print ansMX.response.to_text()
                print()
                print"_______________________ RESPUESTA NS _______________________ "
                print()
                print ansNS.response.to_text()
                print()



    except (dns.resolver.Timeout):
        print("Tiempo de espera superado.. = "+domain)
        print()

    except (dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN):
        print("No se encuentra el dominio = "+domain)
        print()

    except (dns.resolver.NoAnswer):
        print("No hay respuesta = "+domain)
        print()


#defino funcion para crear archivo
def output(f)
    orig_stdout = sys.stdout
    f = open('out.txt', 'w')
    sys.stdout = f
    sys.stdout = orig_stdout
    f.close()


#Defino una funcion para whois
def get_whois(domain):
    command = "whois " + objetivo_1
    process = os.popen(command)
    results = str(process.read())
    print()
    print"_______________________ WHOIS "+domain+" _______________________ "
    print()

try:
    objetivo_1 = raw_input("# Escribe el Dominio_1: ")
    domain = objetivo_1
    get_dns(domain)
    #get_whois(domain)


    objetivo_2 = raw_input("# Escribe el Dominio_2: ")
    domain = objetivo_2
    get_dns(domain)
    #get_whois(domain)



except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print()
    print(" Interrupción recibida, parando…")
```

Comment: Cual es el problema con tu código?

Comment: Pues que no consigo integrar la parte del codigo que sirve para generar un archivo de texto.. a partir de "#defino funcion para crear archivo" el porgrama se cuelga y no vuelca los datos.. he probao mil maneras

Comment: Cuando llamo a la función output  me dice que no esta definida. Ahora la he puesto ahi para mostrar una de las maneras que lo he intentado, pero mi pregunta es como podria hacer lo que quiero, no necesariamente con el codigo que he escrito.

Comment: Si lo pongo en la parte del primer try dentro de la funcion "get_dns", sin definirlo como una función me crea el archivo pero no me vuelca los datos..

Answer (score 0):

Bueno... lo solucionado de la siguiente manera.. aun me faltan algunos retoques pero está casi listo..

```
   # -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

import dns.resolver
import dns.query 
import os
import sys


print" "                                       
print"___________________ INFO-SCANNER DOMAIN ___________________ "
print"                                                            "
print"                Introduzca dos dominios                     "
print"         se le mostrará la siguiente información            "
print"                                                            "
print"          IP, MailServers(MX), DNS(NS) y WHOIS              "
print"                                                            "
print"                    Ejemplo: site.com                       "
print"                                                            "
print"                 Para interrumpir Ctrl + C                  "
print" "


#Defino una funcion para la consulta DNS
def get_dns(domain):


    try:


                ansA,ansMX,ansNS=(dns.resolver.query(domain,'A', raise_on_no_answer=False),
                                  dns.resolver.query(domain,'MX', raise_on_no_answer=False),
                                  dns.resolver.query(domain, 'NS', raise_on_no_answer=False))





                print()
                print"_______________________ RESPUESTA IP _______________________ "
                print()
                print ansA.response.to_text() 
                print()
                print"_______________________ RESPUESTA MX _______________________ "
                print()
                print ansMX.response.to_text()
                print()
                print"_______________________ RESPUESTA NS _______________________ "
                print()
                print ansNS.response.to_text()
                print()     


                f = open('out.txt', 'a' )
                f.write("_______________________ "+domain+" ________________________" + '\n') 
                f.write(ansA.response.to_text() + '\n' )
                f.write(ansMX.response.to_text() + '\n')
                f.write(ansNS.response.to_text() + '\n')
                f.close()



    except (dns.resolver.Timeout):
        print("Tiempo de espera superado.. = "+domain)
        print()

    except (dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN):
        print("No se encuentra el dominio = "+domain)
        print()

    except (dns.resolver.NoAnswer):
        print("No hay respuesta = "+domain)
        print()


#defino funcion para crear archivo
'''def output(f):
    orig_stdout = sys.stdout
    f = open('out.txt', 'w')
    sys.stdout = f
    sys.stdout = orig_stdout
    f.close()'''


#Defino una funcion para whois
def get_whois(domain):
    command = "whois " + objetivo_1
    process = os.popen(command)
    results = str(process.read())
    print()
    print"_______________________ WHOIS "+domain+" _______________________ "
    print()



try:
    objetivo_1 = raw_input("# Escribe el Dominio_1: ")
    domain = objetivo_1
    get_dns(domain)
    #get_whois(domain)


    objetivo_2 = raw_input("# Escribe el Dominio_2: ")
    domain = objetivo_2
    get_dns(domain)
    #get_whois(domain)


except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print()
    print(" Interrupción recibida, parando…")
```

Comment: He añadido el código dentro de la función get_dns

Answer (score 0):

```
 f = open('out.txt', 'a' )
 f.write("_______________________ "+domain+" ________________________" + '\n') 
 f.write(ansA.response.to_text() + '\n' )
 f.write(ansMX.response.to_text() + '\n')
 f.write(ansNS.response.to_text() + '\n')
 f.close()
```

Comment: hola. por favor mira [answer]. Se pide por favor que aclares tu codigo ademas de poner el mismo.

Comment: Buenas gbianchi, gracias por tu repuesta. ¿que es lo que no se entiende del codigo por favor?